# Customize open cart default product search

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, opencart

Hello so far i have done everything good..What i'm trying to do is to add a checkin and checkout..

Where am i going wrong

```
SELECT
   p.product_id,
   (SELECT
      AVG(rating) AS total 
   FROM
      " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 
   WHERE
      r1.product_id = p.product_id  
      AND r1.status = '1' 
   GROUP BY
      r1.product_id) AS rating,
   (SELECT
      price 
   FROM
      " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 
   WHERE
      pd2.product_id = p.product_id 
      AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' 
      AND pd2.quantity = '1' 
      AND (
         (
            pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' 
            OR pd2.date_start < NOW()
         ) 
         AND (
            pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' 
            OR pd2.date_end > NOW()
         )
      ) 
   ORDER BY
      pd2.priority ASC,
      pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount,
   (SELECT
      price 
   FROM
      " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps 
   WHERE
      ps.product_id = p.product_id 
      AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' 
      AND (
         (
            ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' 
            OR ps.date_start < NOW()
         ) 
         AND (
            ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' 
            OR ps.date_end > NOW()
         )
      )

   ORDER BY
      ps.priority ASC,
      ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special
```

I have added **Checkin** and **checkout** to **Product table**

So when a user search i will pass **checkin** and **checkout** dates in the **url**

I have done all the parts but the sql is not working

How can i add **checkin** and **checkout** to this??

Thanks alot..i hope some one will help me :)

Comment: *but the sql is not working* - **what exactly is not working???** Did you get any error (e.g. `MySQL syntax error` or `Column not found`, ...) or what? What is the purpose of *checkin* and *checkout*? Where in your query are you passing the values from URL (I cannot see it in your SQL)?

Comment: i just want to add a check in date and check out date for existing search in opencart